# Google guage chart give Unknown Header Type : 24

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Here is my code which is right as per my knowledge. Because I created similar PIE chart successfully,

Error is : `Unknown Header Type : 24`

I think error is in parsing data from csv file. But it parsed correctly in `string` & `int` form.

Can someone tell what is the issue here.

```
    <html>    
      <head>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/files/jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript">    
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["gauge"]});    
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);    
        function drawChart() {    
           // grab the CSV    
           $.get("Chart2-data.csv", function(csvString) {    
              // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array    
              var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});    
            //alert(arrayData);    
              // this new DataTable object holds all the data    
              var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);   

              // this view can select a subset of the data at a time    
              var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);    
              view.setColumns([0,1]);   

             // set chart options    
             var options = {    
            title: "A Chart from a CSV!",    
            hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},    
            vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},    
            legend: 'none'    
             };   
            var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge'));    
            chart.draw(data, options);    
    });    
          }    
        </script>    
      </head>    
      <body>    
        <div id="gauge" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>    
     </body>
    </html

>
```

csv data:

```
Engine,24

min,34

max,0

yellowFrom,10

yellowTo,6

redFrom,6

redTo,0
```

Comment: I suspect that the csv parser expects to find strings to use as the column headers in the first row, and it is parsing `24` as a number.  Either you need to add column headers to the CSV file, or you need to find an option in your CSV parser to make it not look for column headers.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem.

Using Firebug on my DB result I was able to identify that the problem was that the google library threating a numeric value as an array header.

My array is the following

```
[['234 234  - ',234.00],['234 234  - ',234.00],['cuarta zzzzzzzzz prueba htmlzzzzzzz  - ',654999.00],['fulanita de tal  - ',150.00],['fulanita de tal  - ',133.00],['Mario Alvarez Alvarez - tony',125143.20],['otra5555 prueba5555  - ',1866.00],['prieba de insert actualizando  - ',1101.00],['prueba 888  - ',987.00],['prueba con html  - ',854.00],['prueba de guardado  - ',123.00],['prueba de insert  - ',369.00],['prueba insert actualizando 02 - ',753.00],['prueba666 7777  - ',1547.00],['prueba666 7777  - ',1547.00],['prueba88888 de guardado8888  - ',1576.00],['tercera prueba  - ',98765.00]]
```

My javascript error was:

```
Error: Unknown header type: 234
```

The solution is explained in the Google Visualization API Reference:

> google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(twoDArray, opt_firstRowIsData)
>   [Check this link for detailed info](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)

You have to explicit tell the library that the first row is data, not a header. I add the second parameter true like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(vArray, true);
```

PD: My web app was working fine until a few days ago. I guess google did some change to the library.

Hope my explain will help you